# dropdown Validation not working if it exceeds 50 rows in the Export To Excel

Tags: apache-poi, excel-2010, worksheet-function, xssf

I am generating Excel File(.xlsx) using apache poi jar (poi-ooxml-3.9.jar), I added dropdown validation for 10 columns in my excel file, If I generate the Excel File with 50 rows, drop down validation is working. If it exceeds more than 50 rows, drop down validation is not coming in the Excel File, When I open the excel File I get the message as "**We found a problem with some content  in fileName.xlsx. Do  you want us  to try  to recover as much as we can ? If you trust the source  of this workbook, click Yes** ". when click on Yes, all the dropdown validation it is removing. Kindly need solution to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do **not** create `DataValidationConstraint` for each single cell but only for each varying list you need. Then create `DataValidation` using those `DataValidationConstraint` for continuous `CellRangeAddressList` which are as big as possible and also are **not** all single cells.

Example creates ten different list validations for column 1 to 10 in rows 1 to 10000.

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList;

class DataValidationList {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();  // or new HSSFWorkbook

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Data Validation");
  DataValidationHelper dvHelper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();

  for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
   DataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = dvHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(
    new String[]{"Col "+(col+1)+" one","Col "+(col+1)+" two","Col "+(col+1)+" three"});
   CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 9999, 0, col);            
   DataValidation validation = dvHelper.createValidation(
    dvConstraint, addressList);

   if(validation instanceof XSSFDataValidation) {
    validation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
    validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
   }
   else {
    validation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
   }

   sheet.addValidationData(validation);
  }

  String filename;

  if(workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   filename = "DataValidationList.xlsx";
  } else {
   filename = "DataValidationList.xls";
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```